# Element with margin: auto overlaps floated elements, solution?

Tags: css, css-float, center, margin

I have a div which on most pages I want centered in my content area, I'm accomplishing that via "`margin:5px auto;`".

On a specific page I want to put an image and caption to the right, (like `<div><img /><cite></cite></div>`) and have my original div centered in the remaining space. When I set my new div as `float:right;` it simply overlaps my original div.

What would be the best way to solve this such that my original div could be centered on most pages, but adjust to the side if I place an element beside it? (or I could use a table, or inline styles :(

I have a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/nhaskins/zjZth/

Thanks.

*EDIT*

To clarify I want something where I can have `#right` be of arbitrary width, `#left` will center in the remaining width, and the text will clear below `#left` and flow around `#right`.
If I don't find a solution my fallback will be to override the margin of `#left` with inline styles to position it properly for any given page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer Using jQuery:**

http://jsfiddle.net/zjZth/8/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var margin = (($('#content').width() - $('#right').width()) - $('#left').width() ) / 2;
    $('#left').css('margin-left', margin + 'px');
});
```

---

**Original Answer:**

Easiest solution I can come up with is putting your floating right div outside of your content, then giving your content a right margin equal to the width of your floated div.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zjZth/6/

HTML:

```
<div id="right"></div> 
<div id="content">
<div id="left"></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum etc. etc. hkf uhuhek jfhksd jhgklh wgeluih e d shd ed k uhue f vgkdgku  e fudu ghf ugefkiu gek fwioeugf i ghdsi gusdui djhfk uhuhek jfhksd jhgklh wgeluih e d shd ed k uhue f vgkdgku  e fudu ghf ugefkiu gek fwioeugf i ghdsi gusdui djhfk uhuhek jfhksd jhgklh wgeluih e d shd ed k uhue f vgkdgku  e fudu ghf ugefkiu gek fwioeugf i ghdsi gusdui djhfk</p>
</div>
```

And for the CSS:

```
#content {
    padding: 5px; 
    margin-right:200px;
}

#right {
    background: rgba(0,0,255,0.8);
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#left {
    background: red;
    margin: 5px auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: This solution is valid, but it won't work for me. `#content` is my main article, and I would be cutting it almost in half. I want something where I can have `#right` be of arbitrary width, `#left` will center in the remaining width, and the text will clear below `#left` and flow around `#right`.

Comment: The problem is that your `#left` div *is* centered in `#content` as you want. I don't think there's a way to do this without JavaScript. Here's a fiddle using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/zjZth/8/

Comment: I wanted to avoid JavaScript, for purely emotional reasons, but I'll think about it. It does do what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with floats is that it takes that element out of the normal content flow and it just kind of floats there and doesn't sit nice with other elements. You may just have to use it as an inline element or use a `clear:both`.